# Activity shows blank screen instead of map

Tags: android, google-maps

I followed two tutorials to create an android app that displays a google map. The activity launches but there is no map visible. The zoom buttons on the side are seen though. What do I do to see the map ?

[The Tutorial I used for the project structure](http://android.rzeszow.net/?p=79)

[The Tutorial I used for the activity code](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.application.ridingo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
            android:name="com.application.ridingo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.application.ridingo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.application.ridingo.Select_Route"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="ASDfrughiuniGDWUdhiWHdbi" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you run the code on emulator or real device ?? cause the emulator doesn't support google play services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe usually happens when there is some problem with the way you defined Google Maps permissions (from a quick look at your manifest file the look OK) or from a bad configuration of the of the allowed API in the Google's API Console.

Take a look at this guide I wrote on how to configure Google Maps API V2 and make sure you do all the steps right:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Make sure that you turn on the Google Maps V2 for Android in the console and not the one for web. another thing that looks strange in the manifest file you posted is your key (it looks too short - did you cut it in purpose) if you are not sure with the way you produced you key I would suggest you to go over this guide as well:

[Google Maps API V2 key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: Yes, the key is not my actual key. Its just some junk value I inserted here. I'll look into the links provided.

Comment: Thanks ! You were right about the bad configuration. I hadn't activated the API.

Comment: Both the links are broken :(

Answer (score 0):

try these steps. it worked for me.
change your main layout with this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

change your Activity to fragment activity and follow this code

```
  public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    //implements  GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter 
    {

        private GoogleMap googleMap;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
}
```

check your project properties file google play library reference must be their

```
target=android-10
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

if library reference not than import library project from

> > yoursdkPath\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services
> >     after you had import this library . configure this library into your project